# Touch Pad won't work

Tags: hp-touchpad

I just bought a used HP DV9000T Laptop.  It was supposed to have Windows Vista. However, they uninstalled Vista and installed Ubuntu.  The touchpad won't work.  I looked at the answers for people who had this problem, and I have no idea what they mean.  All I do us use computers, I can't work on them.  I can't get off the desktop screen to anywhere.  What do you suggest?

Comment: Possibly related to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1558362

Comment: There is usually a fn key to toggle the touchpad on and off, make sure to toggle this key.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal window.

Type the following command (or just copy and paste) into the terminal window and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/touchpad_enabled true
```

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1558362)

Please post any errors or if it doesn't work.